# Update a row in Parse.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parse-platform

What I have is when an edit button is clicked the values in two input fields create a new row and the old row is dropped.Below is the code i used but what i want is that the original row is updated and not deleted. [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/uyonek/2) of how using the code below works.

```
editBtn.onclick = function () {
    alert("Edit Btn");
    alert(name.value + " " + Lname.value);


    contact.save(null, {
    success: function (contact) {


        contact.set("FirstName", name.value);
        contact.set("LastName", Lname.value);
        contact.save();

            object.destroy({
                success: function (myObject) {

                alert("destroy");
                location.reload();
               },
                error: function (myObject, error) {

                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                }
              });                                    
             }
          });
         }
```

just to clarify I want to update the rows not create a new one while deleting the old one.

EDIT: [Link](https://www.parse.com/questions/problem-updating-objects) to above question asked in parse forums.

EDIT: more information added in link as a reply to a comment.

EDIT: I added [this code](http://jsbin.com/uyoxep/3/edit) which is actually editing the first name ("NewFname") but It wont update the last name ("NewLname").

```
editBtn.onclick = function () {

                    var query = new Parse.Query(Contact);
                    query.equalTo("LastName", NewLname.value);
                    query.first({
                        success: function (Contact) {
                            Contact.save(null, {
                                success: function (contact) {

                                    contact.set('FirstName', NewFname.value);
                                    contact.set('LastName', NewLname.value);

                                    contact.save();
                                    location.reload();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Where I have query.equalTo("LastName", NewLname.value), I tried to put in objectId i.e. (query.equalTo("objectId"); but that didn't work for me.

any ideas?

Thomas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to get it updating with this code.

```
editBtn.onclick = function () {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Contact);
    query.equalTo("objectId", object.id);
    query.first({
        success: function (Contact) {
            Contact.save(null, {
                success: function (contact) {
                    contact.set("FirstName", NewFname.value);
                    contact.set("LastName", NewLname.value);
                    contact.save();
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```