# Updating an object in parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have seen a solution here: [Update a row in Parse.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444458/update-a-row-in-parse-com), and I have tried to adapt this solution:

```
function save(){
var objectId = $.cookie("objectId");
var saveTheThing = Parse.Object.extend("userSavedSearches");
var query = new Parse.Query(objectId);
query.equalTo("objectId", objectId);
query.first({
 success: function (Contact) {
  Contact.save(null, { /* Here I get error Contact is not defined*/
   success: function (contact) {

     contact.set($.cookie("weWant"), mySwiper.activeIndex);
     contact.set("savedSoFar", $.cookie("weSay"));
     contact.save();
   }
  });
 }, error: function(user, error) {
     alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);}
});

}
```

But strangely, I get an error telling me that `Contact` is not defined. I have triple checked that all the values I have are valid.

The strange thing here is that if I change `query.first` to `query.find`, `Contact` is now defined but I get an error telling me that I can't update an object using `query.find` i.e `Contact.save` is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? I think it accomplishes the same thing you're trying to accomplish.

```
query.first({
    success: function(contact) {
        contact.set($.cookie("weWant"), mySwiper.activeIndex);
        contact.set("savedSoFar", $.cookie("weSay"));
        contact.save();
    }, 
    error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});
```